# How to drop entire group in pandas if any other columns meet certain criteria?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df that looks like this:

```
Name  Letter  Period  Amount
123   H       PRE     11 
123   H       DURING  5
123   H       POST    100
456   H       PRE     9
456   H       DURING  50
456   H       POST    600
789   J       PRE     8
789   J       DURING  9
789   J       POST    200
```

Currently, I am using this line of code to filter on the df so that only rows that are of a period PRE and have an amount of more than 10 are included:

```
revised_data[ (revised_data['Period'] == 'PRE' ) & (revised_data['Amount'] > 10)]
```

What I realized though is that I actually need to remove the entire grouping from the df if even just the PRE period doesn't satisfy the > 10 condition. So in that case I would need all 456 rows and 789 rows removed just because their PRE period row was below 10. How might I adjust my code to accomplish this?

Expected Output:

```
Name  Letter  Period  Amount
123   H       PRE     11 
123   H       DURING  5
123   H       POST    100
```

Comment: expected output please

Comment: my apologies. just updated the question to reflect expected output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try:

```
df.loc[df['Name'].isin(df['Name'].loc[ (df['Period'] == 'PRE' ) & (df['Amount'] > 10)])]
```

Prints:

```
   Name Letter  Period  Amount
0   123      H     PRE      11
1   123      H  DURING       5
2   123      H    POST     100
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets try:

get a new column/grouper which is a group of each cycle in each group of letters:

```
df.groupby(['Letter','Period']).cumcount()
```

Now group df by letter and new grouper. In each of the resulting group, filter out any PRE period which is gt than 10. See solution below.

```
g=df.groupby(['Letter',df.groupby(['Letter','Period']).cumcount()]).filter(lambda x: ((x['Period'].eq('PRE'))&(x['Amount'].gt(10))).any())



 Name Letter  Period  Amount
0   123      H     PRE      11
1   123      H  DURING       5
2   123      H    POST     100
```